# swift: iClouds Documents seems to be disabled when loaded from custom application

Tags: ios, swift, icloud

i am trying to upload the PDF files from iCloud in my custom application. But as i move to iCloud from my application the documents cannot be selected it seems like as if they are disabled. Most of all the explanations are in Obj-C so i could no understand exactly.

What is wrong here? This is my code in swift2:

```
    import UIKit
import MobileCoreServices
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIDocumentPickerDelegate, UITextViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var emailButton: UIButton!
     @IBOutlet weak var UITextField: UITextView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.

    }

    @IBAction func handleImportPickerPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
        let documentPicker = UIDocumentPickerViewController(documentTypes: [kUTTypeText as NSString as String], inMode: .Import)
        documentPicker.delegate = self
        presentViewController(documentPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func documentPicker(controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController, didPickDocumentAtURL url: NSURL) {


        print(url)
    }
```

Comment: i did not get you :)

Comment: Don't cast twice! You are casting kUTTypeText to NSString and then casting it again to String. This makes no sense. Just cast it directly to the needed type once and for all.

Comment: ok i have done [kUTTypeText as String]. but still same problem

Comment: Well, I wasn't talking about fixing your issue. I was talking about this specific part of the code... My message is "Remember in the future to not cast twice."

Comment: yes i will keep in mind that :)

Comment: so can you also tell me about my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are disable means that document types you have in your iCloud does not match while your are selecting.Use documents types as:

```
 @IBAction func handleImportPickerPressed(sender: AnyObject) {

    let documentPicker = UIDocumentPickerViewController(documentTypes:["public.data", "public.text"],inMode:  UIDocumentPickerMode.Import)
    documentPicker.delegate = self
    documentPicker.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.FormSheet
    presentViewController(documentPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

There are many other document types. They are disable means that they cannot be read by the **documentTypes** you are passing.